# Calling WCF-Webservice from ASP.NET-Webapp using Windows Authentication: Error 401

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a WCF-Webservice that should be called from an ASP.NET-Webapplication (Webform). Both are hostet in an IIS using Windows Authentication. Both are deployed to the same Website.

When I call the ASP-Webform, the browser is asking for the credentials, and after I entered the correct credentials it returns the Webform, so I guess the windows authentication is working. Unfortunately, the call to the WCF-Webservice, which is done in the page results in a HTTP-Status 401. Unauthorized.

Here is how I call the WCF-Service from the WebForm1.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WcfService.ServiceWA client = new WcfService.ServiceWA();
  WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

  Response.Write(wi.Name);
  // just to check wheter I got the right credentials
  // it results in the expected DOMAIN\username output

  WindowsImpersonationContext context = wi.Impersonate();
  try
  {
    Response.Write(client.GetData(1, true));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    // here I always get the 401 message
  }
  finally
  {
    context.Undo();
  }
}
```

The web.config of the WCF-Service looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="false"/>

    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WindowsAuthentication.ServiceWABehavior">
      <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>


  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WindowsAuthentication.ServiceWABehavior"
                                                     name="WindowsAuthentication.ServiceWA">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="WindowsAuthentication.IServiceWA">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
                        binding="mexHttpBinding"
                        address="mex" />

        </service>
    </services>

</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    Um das Stammverzeichnis der Webanwendung beim Debuggen auszuwählen, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest.
    Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Informationen über den Webanwendungsordner zu vermeiden.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

In the IIS 7, that is hosting both WCF and Webpage, under Authentication only Windows-Authentication is active. Activated Providers are: NTLM, Negotiate

Any ideas, what might be the problem?

Comment: Try running the application pool identity as a domain user.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't help in my case